# What is the established drone racing etiquette?

Tags: racing, rules

As I understand it, at drone races there are lots of rules to follow pre and post flight, an obvious one that jumps to mind is to shout ‘plugging in’ before plugging in.

What other rules and best practices are there to make sure races operate smoothly?

I understand that different clubs may have slightly different rules, but as long as there is a consensus on the general kind of rules there are, I’d appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I run a small MultiGP chapter, so things are slightly more relaxed in our chapter compared to some of the big chapters. But here are the official MultiGP rules for pilots:

- Fly only in designated areas.
- Fly only at appropriate times.
- Keep your multirotor at least (30) feet away from the pilot area. Flying any closer can
  cause your video transmitter to interfere with other pilot’s reception.
- When finishing a race, land ON the course (at least 30 feet away from the pilot area)
- When flying on the course, you must be positioned within the designated Pilot Area.
  DO NOT fly from any other area.
- Only power up your multirotor/video transmitter while in the Start/Finish area on the course. DO NOT
  power up in the pits or while walking from the pits to the course
- If you need to check your video channel or change frequency, this MUST be completed between heats. You
  MUST also ensure you have the appropriate Frequency Card for the frequency you wish to check.
- If you are flying before or after the event you MUST ensure you have the appropriate Frequency Card for the
  frequency you are using.
- You MUST ensure you have a Spotter in the Pilot Area while flying. A Spotter observes the course for
  dangers such as members of public, animals, other model fliers, low flying aircraft or vehicles. Spotters
  stand in the Pilot Area to ensure clear communication.
- You should help with spotting for the heat before yours.

And some more rules we incorporate:

- If video channels are assigned ahead of time, be sure to show up with all of your drones set to that channel (though changing after arriving is not unusual).
- All transmitters (video and remote) should be set to 25mW to prevent someone knocking others out the air.
- Never enter the race coarse unless the safety officer gives you permission. But keep an eye out for people who might fly during inappropriate times.

Comment: Excellent answer and very clear, thank you!